# Why is Valgrind stating that my implementation of std::map<T, T> produces a memory leak?

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind is outputting the following:

```
==14446== 2,976 (176 direct, 2,800 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 23 of 33
==14446==    at 0x4C2506C: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/amd64-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==14446==    by 0x41C487: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:92)
==14446==    by 0x41C4AB: std::_Rb_tree<unsigned, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> >, std::less<unsigned>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::_M_get_node() (stl_tree.h:357)
==14446==    by 0x41C915: std::_Rb_tree<unsigned, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> >, std::less<unsigned>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::_M_create_node(std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> const&) (stl_tree.h:366)
==14446==    by 0x5036E9A: std::_Rb_tree<unsigned, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> >, std::less<unsigned>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> const&) (stl_tree.h:852)
==14446==    by 0x5037027: std::_Rb_tree<unsigned, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> >, std::less<unsigned>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::_M_insert_unique(std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> const&) (stl_tree.h:1148)
==14446==    by 0x5037227: std::_Rb_tree<unsigned, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> >, std::less<unsigned>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::_M_insert_unique_(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> >, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> const&) (stl_tree.h:1188)
==14446==    by 0x50375CD: std::map<unsigned, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn, std::less<unsigned>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::insert(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> >, std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> const&) (stl_map.h:496)
==14446==    by 0x50376DE: std::map<unsigned, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn, std::less<unsigned>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned const, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixColumn> > >::operator[](unsigned const&) (stl_map.h:419)
==14446==    by 0x5036A43: vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrixRow::operator[](unsigned) (ImageMatrixRow.cpp:10)
==14446==    by 0x5034BBB: vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrix::_getRotatedCopy(double, vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrix&) (ImageMatrix.cpp:151)
==14446==    by 0x503350A: vimrid::imaging::processing::ImageFilter& vimrid::imaging::ImageMatrix::GetRotatedCopy<vimrid::imaging::processing::ImageFilter>(double) (ImageMatrix.h:48)
```

What could this possibly mean?

```
//ImageMatrixRow.cpp:8-11
ImageMatrixColumn &ImageMatrixRow::operator[](VUInt32 columnIndex)
{
    return columns[columnIndex];
}

//ImageMatrix.cpp:151
target[x][y][0] = source[roundX][roundY][0];

//ImageMatrix.h:48
return *(T*)&_getRotatedCopy(degrees, CopyDimensions());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because of a pool allocator. From Valgrind FAQ:

> My program uses the C++ STL and
>   string classes. Valgrind reports
>   'still reachable' memory leaks
>   involving these classes at the exit of
>   the program, but there should be
>   none.
>
> First of all: relax, it's probably not
>   a bug, but a feature. Many
>   implementations of the C++ standard
>   libraries use their own memory pool
>   allocators. Memory for quite a number
>   of destructed objects is not
>   immediately freed and given back to
>   the OS, but kept in the pool(s) for
>   later re-use. The fact that the pools
>   are not freed at the exit() of the
>   program cause Valgrind to report this
>   memory as still reachable. The
>   behaviour not to free pools at the
>   exit() could be called a bug of the
>   library though.

Read more at:
[Valgrind Faq](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports)

I may be wrong, as I'm in a hurry and I can't analyse your code.

Answer (score 1):

The error does not seem to come from your code, but a library you are using.

Valgrind comes with some default error suppression, but that probably does not cover the library you are using.

> The error-checking tools detect numerous problems in the base libraries, such as the GNU C library, and the X11 client libraries, which come pre-installed on your GNU/Linux system. You can't easily fix these, but you don't want to see these errors (and yes, there are many!) So Valgrind reads a list of errors to suppress at startup. A default suppression file is created by the ./configure script when the system is built.

You can create your own [error suppressions](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) that you know are irrelevant to your code.

See the similar SO question [Why does Valgrind not like my usage of glutCreateWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766303/why-does-valgrind-not-like-my-usage-of-glutcreatewindow)